# How Do i Determine an Ideal MongoDB hosting package

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I am working on a small app that will soon go into production and I would like to understand the amount of RAM and Storage that would be required for the first hundreds to thousands to millions of requests, how many requests can 1GB RAM handle on average and how much storage would be ideal.

If for example I am getting 1,000 requests per hour or per minute, what would be an ideal configuration.

Any detailed resource explaining this would also be appreciated